# Quarter Data to month data

Tags: python, dataframe, date

I have a Dataframe with a column Date. The date is written as 2002Q1, 2002Q2,....

I like to have for every quarter three lines instead of one and rename the date as 20020101, 20020201 and 20020301 as an example for the first quarter.

Do you have any idea. Thank you

My Code

```
    list=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Usersxyx.csv", delimiter = ',', usecols=["date", "ID", 'Value'])
list['year'] = [str(i)[:4] for i in list["date"]]
list ['month']= [str(i)[5:6] for i in list["date"]]
blist= pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(list.values, 3, axis=0))
blist.columns = list.columns
```

My idea was to copy the row three times. So that I have a line for every month. And now I have no clue how i can change the Date from 2001Q1 in 20010101 20010201 and so.

Comment: How do you intend to split the aggregate data into individual months? Does a quarter with a value of 300 correspond to three months of 100 each, one with 50, one with 100, and one with 150?

Comment: no it would correspond to threetimes 300. The values of the other coulms should be untouched

Comment: i edited my question. I thought my code wouldnt be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow below code. 
Note: don't use dataframe name as 'list'. I change the name as 'lista'

```
a1=pd.DataFrame([str(i)[0:4]+str((int(str(i)[5]))*3-2).zfill(2)+'01' for i in lista["date"]],columns= ['date1'])
a2=pd.DataFrame([str(i)[0:4]+str((int(str(i)[5]))*3-1).zfill(2)+'01' for i in lista["date"]],columns= ['date1'])
a3=pd.DataFrame([str(i)[0:4]+str((int(str(i)[5]))*3).zfill(2)+'01' for i in lista["date"]],columns= ['date1'])
pd.concat([a1,a2,a3])   
pd.concat([pd.concat([lista,a1],axis=1),pd.concat([lista,a2],axis=1),pd.concat([lista,a3],axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: i get the error: a1=pd.DataFrame([str(i)[0:4]+str((int(str(i)[5]))*3-2).zfill(2)+'01' for i in lista["date"]],columns= ['date1'])

IndexError: string index out of range. The problem is with str(i)[5]. Do you know why because [5] should be in range

Comment: please check your date column in your DataFrame. There may be some value at that column which didn't follow 'yyyyQn' (as you say 2002Q1 or so on). If you find anything which is different than you need to first decide what you want to do with that kind of situation.